# How to create an asterisk pattern through string? (C#)

Tags: c#

So I'm a new programmer studying C# and have created asterisk patterns before with nested loops and stuff. However, my teacher gave us this question and I'm not entirely sure what it means or how to go about solving it. the question is:

"Write a method called BoxMaker that takes two parameters, width and height. The method needs to build a box in a string using asterisks for the given width and height and return it."

This is what I have:

```
public static void BoxMaker(int height, int width)
{
    int num = 1;

    while (num <= height)
    {
        if (num == 1 || num == height)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= width; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            int num2 = 1;
            while (num2 <= width)
            {
                if (num2 == 1 || num2 == width)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");

                }
                num2++;
            }

        }
        num++;
        Console.WriteLine();


    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

What does he mean by building a box in a string?

Comment: Have you considered asking *him* what he means?  That seems more likely to get the correct answer than asking a random group of people on the internet.

Comment: Yeah I emailed him but in the meantime I was hoping someone might know what he was talking about

Comment: I would say, that he mean, you should build the output to string, not to console. You can use `StringBuilder` instead of `Console` and then return the value as string.

Comment: Every instructor has their own idea. I had one who wanted us to construct a word with asterisks in a PictureBox (for a VB6 class), but when you did exactly that, he'd say, "No! No! It has to be centered!" or some other arbitrary thing that was never stated in the first place. Requirements can be tricky things at this early stage. Only the teacher can truly say what he meant because he's the one ultimately judging your work.

Comment: Also if he used this word “pattern”, there may be more to it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have it down ... but instead of Console.Write, concatenate your asterisks in a string variable.  Use \r\n to add carriage-return/line-feed at the end of each line once you count up to width.  At the end, dump the box variable to the console in one shot:

```
    public static void BoxMaker(int height, int width)
    {
        int num = 1;
        string box = "";
        while (num <= height)
        {
            if (num == 1 || num == height)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= width; i++)
                {
                    box += "*";
                    if (i == width) box += "\r\n";
                }
            }

            else
            {
                int num2 = 1;
                while (num2 <= width)
                {
                    if (num2 == 1 || num2 == width)
                    {
                        box += "*";
                        if (num2 == width) box += "\r\n";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        box += " ";
                    }
                    num2++;
                }
            }
            num++;
        }
        Console.Write(box);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

BoxMaker(10,10) outputs:

```
> **********
> *        *
> *        *
> *        *
> *        *
> *        *
> *        *
> *        *
> *        *
> **********
```

If your program is responsible for landing the space shuttle, you want to be pedantic about it, or are simply looking to avoid those rascally code analysis warnings, your optimal code might look like:

```
    public static void BoxMaker(int height, int width)
    {
        string cap = new string('*', width);
        string middle = "*" + new string(' ', width - 2) + "*"; 

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = height; i-- > 0;)
            if (i % (height-1) == 0) sb.AppendLine(cap);
            else sb.AppendLine(middle);

        string box = sb.ToString();

        Console.Write(box);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Do not use string in such a way. Code analysers says: "CC0039: Don't concatenate 'box' in a loop" or "S1643:Use a StringBuilder instead." Concatenating string in a loop is not a good way.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void DrawBox(int h, int w)
{
   var hoz = new string('*', w);
   var vet = "*" + new string(' ', w - 2) + "*";

   Console.WriteLine(hoz);
   for (var i = 0; i < h - 2; i++)
      Console.WriteLine(vet);
   Console.WriteLine(hoz);
}
```

or

```
public static void DrawBox(int h, int w)
{
   Console.WriteLine(new string('*', w));
   for (var i = 0; i < h-2; i++)
      Console.WriteLine($"*{new string(' ', w - 2)}*");
   Console.WriteLine(new string('*', w));
}
```

Score extra points by validating the arguments

```
public static void DrawBox(int h, int w)
{
   if (h < 2) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(h));
   if (w < 2) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(w));
```

**Usage**

```
DrawBox(5, 5);
```

**Output**

```
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4B0rFc)

---

**Additional Resources**

[String(Char, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_)

> Initializes a new instance of the String class to the value indicated
>   by a specified Unicode character repeated a specified number of times.